# Reason and solution of "*** Error in `python': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000000ff2460 ***" in Python

Tags: python, sql, azure

I created a service using Python which connects to SQL Azure using `pymssql` and only makes `SELECT` queries. After 1 day (or a bit more), the connection begins to fail in queries and finally the service ends with the error:

```
Error in `python': free(): corrupted unsorted chunks: 0x0000000000ff2460
```

I am not be sure if there is only one error or more (maybe the first error provokes more errors).

The code of connection is here:

```
  connectionDb = pymssql.connect(host=self.HOST_DATA_BASE, user=self.USER_DATA_BASE, password=self.PASSWORD_DATA_BASE, database=self.DATA_BASE_NAME)
```

and I execute the query in the next form:

```
  cursor=connectionDb.cursor()
  cursor.execute("select * from vehicles") 
  rows = cursor.fetchall()

  if (rows!=None):
     return rows
```

Initially, the connection works fine. The problem occurs after a time of inactivity.

I tried to simplify the queries but I don´t believe that is the reason of error.

*Maybe it is possible bug in `pymssql`?

Comment: Did you try a web search with the error message, or part of it?  I did and there are hits, but I did not try to followup.

Comment: yes i try, but the context of errors is different, i see only with make extensions between c++ and python

Comment: Can my answer marked as the correct answer, the proof to why this answer is correct is included in the ticket I linked.I also included an explanation of the garbage collection output

Answer (score 4):

Okay so I was able to verify that this is a memory issue within pymssql. There is an open ticket out for this.

I used the python garbage collection library (gc) to print how much memory has not been freed up by Python.

Below is the garbage collection outputs. As you can see 'collections' continues to increase, meaning that pymssql did not free the memory even though it was no longer in use.

```
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1822693, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 165699, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4173, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1823867, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 165806, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4176, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1825043, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 165912, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4178, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1826218, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166019, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4180, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1827393, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166126, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4182, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1828567, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166233, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4185, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1829741, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166340, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4188, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1830917, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166446, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4190, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1832092, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166553, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4192, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1833267, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166660, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4194, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 1834441, 'collected': 54744, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 166767, 'collected': 863905, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 4197, 'collected': 359393, 'uncollectable': 0}]


free(): corrupted unsorted chunks
```

When I switched to pyodbc I ran the same code and got the following:

```
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
garbage collector output is [{'collections': 218, 'collected': 806, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 19, 'collected': 115, 'uncollectable': 0}, {'collections': 1, 'collected': 5, 'uncollectable': 0}]
```

As you can see 'collections' element stays constant. This proves that there is a memory leak issue with pymssql. My recommendation is to use pyodbc, pytds, or ctds. I made a point about this on the  [github ticket](https://github.com/pymssql/pymssql/issues/500)

Answer (score 2):

@APRocha, It seems to be not a bug of pymssql, it's an error from glibc when python free some malloc memory.

Did you close the connection after done the sql opertion per request? If not, I suggest you do, or using SQLAlchemy with pymssql to manage the connections in a pool.

Otherwise, I think you can try to use `gc.collect()` to release the unreferenced memory at intervals, please refer to the [document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html) as reference.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I think first use the gc.collect() by intervals, and after maybe i try to close and open the connection by intervals too.

Comment: Hi @APRocha, did this solved your problem? I am facing the same issue while using this library but `gc.collect()` didn't solve it. Did someone figure why it happens?

Comment: Well, really i don't resolve completely this issue, i change the library and the process, i can only say change library.

Comment: I have exact the same problem also using pymssql and the problem persists with the use of `gc.collect()`. I have no idea how to avoid this.

Comment: Has anyone had any luck using gc.collect() to solve the issue?

Comment: @DomingoR look at my answer, I used gc.collect() to prove what the issue is